# Proper way to manage offline database with many large images and with update feature

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In my current project I need to handle a **large database** of many **large size images** and the application should run in **offline** mode. The application need to **sync** the latest data with the server.

Some of images are having size of around **5 Mb**

1. One approach is to download a **zip** containing the data when application start first time and store their reference in **SQLite** database.
2. Other approach we can use is to download all data from service in **JSON** format when application launch first time.

Is their any other more suitable method I can use for this application? Should I store images in SQLite database?
How can I sync the latest changes with server?